# Saving values from JavaScript inner callback function

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

I realize JavaScript callbacks have been explained over and over, but I don't seem to find a way to save values from an inner callback function.

```
request.get('http://google.com', function(error, response, body){
    var $ = cheerio.load(body);
    // Process HTML here
    // How do I save the result from processing with a callback
}

// Or
var parse = function(error, response, body){
    // Process HTML here
    // Assign result to a variable or pass a callback to this function
};
request.get('http://google.com', parse);
```

I have multiple urls to process and I'd like to have one object summarizing the information afterwards.

By saving I mean either assigning to a variable or saving to a file.

Comment: Save how? Save where? What do you want to do with it afterwards? When is "afterwards", why not just do the summarisation inside the callback?

Comment: you may return the result

Comment: use another callback

Comment: @Redu: For sure not.

Comment: Sounds like you should be using a promise chain to carry relevant data through a pipeline.

Comment: Put the variable outside of the callback. And don't call it `$`.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that the callback will be called when the async operation completes (like a second thread), meaning that the code after `request.get` will have been already executed then and you can't use `return` to send values back.

The solution is to make all the process inside the callback or to have other functions. Instead of returning the value, just make and call `next_function(the_return_value)` (something like that).

Comment: Well, say I created another function that does the processing, and passed it as a callback, which I've done, how would I pass a callback to the outer callback function ?